# Prove that the triangles $VAC, EAV$ are similar if and only if $\angle EVO=30°$.

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, triangles, angle

**The question**

The regular quadrilateral pyramid $VABCD$ has the vertex $V$. Let $M$ be the middle of the edge $AD$ and $E$ be the point of intersection of the lines $AC$ and $BM$. Prove that the triangles $VAC, EAV$ are similar if and only if the angle formed by the right $VE$ with the plane $(VBD)$ measures $30°$.

**The drawing**

[image]

the angle formed by the right $VE$ with the plane $(VBD)$ its actually angle $EVO=30°$

let $AC=6x => AE=2x, EC=4x, EO=x, AO=3x$

**Case 1**: We know that $\angle EVO=30$. We show that $VAC$ and $EAV$ are similar.

$\angle EVO=30°, \angle VOE=90°=> VE=2x => VO=x\sqrt{3} => VA=2x\sqrt{3}$

From here we can say that its verified $\frac{VA}{AE}=\frac{AC}{AV}=\frac{VC}{VE}=\sqrt{3}$ which makes $VAC, EAV$ similar.

**Case 2**: We show that $\angle EVO=30°$. We know that $VAC$ and $EAV$ are similar.

From the similarity we get that $\frac{VA}{AE}=\frac{AC}{AV}=\frac{VC}{VE}=> VA^2=AC\times AE=12x^2=> VA=2x\sqrt{3},AO=3x=> VO=x\sqrt{3}=> \angle VAO=30°=> \angle AVO=60$

we can show that $\frac{AE}{EO}=\frac{AV}{VO}=2$ which makes $VE$ an bisector $=> \angle EVO=30°$

I'm not sure if my calculation and rationament (the bisector thing) are right. Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify what is a "regular quadrilateral"? (Mainly I'm wondering why you didn't just say it's a square based pyramid.) $\quad$ Also, must $V$ be above the center of the regular quadrilateral? (That's not stated, but seems to be so in your diagram.)

Comment: @CalvinLin They are the same thing... i translated the text and this is what it gave me, so I thought that "regular quadrilateral" is more used....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1**: Well done; you could have just specified that $VC=VA(=2x\sqrt3)$

**Case 2**: Well done; you could have quoted the [angle bissector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem) and perhaps write more classicaly $\frac{V\color{red}A}{V\color{red}O}=\frac{\color{red}AE}{\color{red}OE}$ :)